# Javascript / REST / Activiti - What am I doing wrong in my XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, rest, activiti

I'm trying to learn how to use the Activiti REST api and I'm have trouble getting back data. I'm not very familiar with using rest apis so I may be making a stupid mistake, but as it stands I can't figure it out.

I've had success getting back JSON using the Advanced REST Client for Chrome but I can't seem to implement it with Javascript.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Links to relevant tutorials and videos would also be much appreciated.

```
   window.onload = function get_json() {

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://kermit:kermit@localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions";
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    hr.open("GET", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(hr.readystate == 4 && hr.status == 200) {

            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            result.innerHTML = data;

        }

    }

    hr.send();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems. The main is that it's `readyState`, not `readystate`. So it should be

```
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
        result.innerHTML = data;
    }
}
```

The second problem is that you probably don't want to just assign object to `innerHTML` because it will be meaningless `[object Object]`. But rendering of the data is beyond this question.

Comment: I feel very silly, but I was prepared for such a simple mistake. Thanks. I've got the rendering of the data down I think. I just assigned the object to innerHTML just to test that I got something back.